# jQuery find style attr of ID

Tags: jquery, attr

How can I find the style attribute of a particular ID element?

E.g

```
desc = "#thisID";
desc_style = desc.attr('style');
console.log(desc_style);
```

Edit for clarification, above is an example.

Desc variable holds string #thisID.

How do I find the style attribute of that ID?

Comment: desc = $("#thisID");  Don't forget to include jquery to your html head tag

Comment: `"#thisID"` is string not jquery object.

Comment: OK, this was just an example. The desc is a string. How do I find the attribute of that ID?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)

Comment: `$("#thisID").attr("style")`

Comment: @AlexChar this works please add as an answer so I can mark correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mention in my comment `desc` is a string not an jquery object, so you can't use jquery methods. You can simple use:

```
$("#thisID").attr("style");
```

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery object is returned with this syntax

```
desc = $("#thisID");
```

you can then get the style as you were doing

```
desc_style = desc.attr('style');
console.log(desc_style);
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to keep `desc` as a string, do this:

```
desc = "#thisID"
desc_style = $(desc).attr('style');
console.log(desc_style);
```

Comment: I have clarified in OP. The code was an example. #thisID is correctly stored in a string. How do I find the style attribute contents of that ID?

Answer (score 0):

If `desc` holding string `#thisID`, then

```
desc_style = $(desc).attr('style');
console.log(desc_style);
```

Or, if `desc` only holding `thisID`, then you need to concat `#` before it

```
desc_style = $("#" + desc).attr('style');
console.log(desc_style);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
("'"+desc+"'").css("styleToGet","settingItIsOptional");
```

if desc is a string value of `#MyElementsID`

If you just wanted to remove the desc altogether, you can use:

```
("#MyDivID").css("styleToGet","settingItIsOptional");
```

---

I believe getting the `attr("style")` may or may not be a better option here, but it depends on your requirements I suppose.